# Python passing values from command line

Tags: python

I want to pass a value into my python script, as shown in the below image

[image]

Where, xyz would be my python file which requires the abc value.

How do I do this and access the abc value in xyz.py?

Comment: u should use `str(sys.argv)` before that user `import sys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python sys module provides access to any command-line arguments via the sys.argv. This serves two purpose:

sys.argv is the list of command-line arguments.

len(sys.argv) is the number of command-line arguments.

Example:
Consider the following script test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Now run above script as follows:

```
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This will produce following result:

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

[command line arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sys.argv` but better approach is to use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module.

here is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='reader', description='Read commandline value.')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--value')
args = parser.parse_args()
print "Value you entered: %s" % args.value
```

Comment: Why is argparse a better method? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Zedai : sorry for late reply, have a  look at this [argparse vs sys.argv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310631/using-argparse-as-opposed-to-sys-argv) and this too,  [using argparse in conjunction with sys.argv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423895/using-argparse-in-conjunction-with-sys-argv-in-python) I hope this helps.